# Character Foot Pivot

Tags: rigging

I'm trying to animate this cool looking jump kick, but I'm running into a snag.

[image: 540 Kick]

At the point where he first turns, he pivots, switching his weight from left to right, while turning on his right foot before taking off and doing the kick.

**The problem:** When I rotate my character, the foot drags across the floor. I tried adding an Empty as a marker to pivot on, and I adjusted the leg bones frame-by-frame, and it still looks horribly unconvincing.

Is there a way to lock the right foot to a point in space, leaving the other joints in the leg free to move?

Here's the video of the guy doing the kickbif you need to see it slower.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCqlZrwrABY

Comment: Can't you use the IK control of the foot?

Comment: You can always lock position of the foot controlling bone, but I don't think it's a good idea to do that in this example. As you can see on the video, pivot point of the rotation of the man is rather his lower body/crotch then foot which goes in a circle around this pivot point.